# How to run Wolfram language using Wolfram Client Library for Python in Google colab?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, python

How to run the Wolfram language using **Wolfram Client Library for Python** in Google colab?

Answer (score 6):

[Herein](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConnectPythonToTheWolframCloud.html) lies the answer.

Since a short answer is not accepted:

sign in to wolframcloud.com and get the key from there. The process is detailed in the link.

Then on colab:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframCloudSession, SecuredAuthenticationKey
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr, wl
key = SecuredAuthenticationKey(
'3274928379750=',
'987345h87598375=')
session = WolframCloudSession(credentials=key)
session.start()
session.authorized()
session.evaluate('1+1')

## this was fun
a = session.evaluate(wlexpr("RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1,2], 100]"))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(a)
```

Have fun :)